# How to customize tool tip window to have arrow in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

How to customize tooltip window to have a corner arrow like shown below in WPF(xaml).

[image]

I have my code like below

```
 <Image x:Name="imgInfoTab">
            <Image.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip Background="WhiteSmoke" HasDropShadow="True" 
       Cursor="Hand">
          <TextBlock Width="250" Height="250"                                                         
      TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"                                                                                                                             
       Cursor="Hand">                                                   
        </TextBlock>
        </ToolTip>
       </Image.ToolTip>
        </Image>
```

It looks as below with above code,
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style WPF tooltip like a speech bubble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446250/how-to-style-wpf-tooltip-like-a-speech-bubble)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="CornflowerBlue">
    <Grid.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Placement="MousePoint" HorizontalOffset="50">
            <ToolTip.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                    <Grid>
                        <Path Fill="White" Data="M 0,10 L 40,10 50,0 60,10 100,10 100,60 0,60" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToolTip.Template>
        </ToolTip>
    </Grid.ToolTip>
</Grid>
```

[image]

If you want it auto-sizing then you'll need to do [a bit more work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972335/how-to-position-tooltip-bottom-center), but that will get you started.

Comment: I suppose you meant `HorizontalOffset="-50"`, i find it visually better with a little `VerticalOffset="5"`

Comment: Interesting. `HorizontalOffset="50"` produces the correct result on my machine, while `HorizontalOffset="-50" does not.

Comment: Yes Interesting !

Comment: Hey, It works but i don't understand what is data in path and how to increase width and height of it as at present I have a huge content to show and not just "Hello world!"